# How to make fields required for one type of user but not others? (registration and profile forms)

Tags: users

I would like to know what is the best way to handle this scenario using Drupal 7.

The issue I am facing is that the Join (registration) forms, and Profile forms are different for all 4 types of users I am working with. The registration and profile forms are all connected to one master profile form. This means that if a field is required for one, it will be for all of users, how can I avoid this? What is the best way to go about it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Required By role](https://drupal.org/project/required_by_role)

> Field required by role is a module that improves core "required"
>   functionality.
>
> Similar to CCK Required by role brings extra features such as:
>
> Ready for all entities, including custom entities. Doesn´t need extra
>   configuration, just install. Respects previous configuration.
>   Configuration per field instance.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it by [hook_form_alter](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_form_alter/7). Alter the **#required** attribute of field according to specific condition.

For example:

```
function mymodule_form_alter(&$form,&$form_state) {
    if ($form_id == 'user_register_form') {
      $form['profile_detailp']['field_name']['und']['#required']=0;
   }

}
```